# Why is my list not stacking on top of each other?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a fixed header menu bar at the top of the webpage. Each of the titles is a link but I want a dropdown for the first link. The link components for the dropdown menu is behaving strangely, see image:

[image]

I would like the link components to be stacked on top of each other, like a proper dropdown. Below is my code:

It looks correct when I run the code snippet but when I did these codings in Visual Studio, the codings below looks just like the image.

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };

// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* List for header */
.navlist {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.navlist li {
  float: left;
}

.navlist a{
  display:block;
  padding:8px;
  transition:0.3s;
}

.navlist a:hover{
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.navlist a[href="#Quiclinks"] {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.navlist>li{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul class="navlist">
        <li>
          <a href="#news">Quicklinks<i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
          <div>
            <a href="#">All Documents</a>
            <a href="#">Divisional Websites</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#news">Intro & News </a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">Programmes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">Benefits</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">Location</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: weird it looks different when its run as code snippet oO

Comment: I changed my answer (see below) and used an snippet  ;) is it better?

Answer (score 0):

this is because your css have :

```
.navlist li {
  float: left;
}
```

just remove it and add  to .navlist a

```
  clear: both;
}
```

complete code :

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* List for header */
.navlist {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

/* just example */
.navlist div {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.navlist a{
  display:block;
  padding:8px;
  transition:0.3s;
  /* adding :  ( work with -- float: left -- allready present in -- .navbar a  -- */
  clear: both;
}

.navlist a:hover{
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.navlist a[href="#Quiclinks"] {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.navlist>li{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul class="navlist">
      <li>
        <a href="#news">Quicklinks <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
        <div>
          <a href="#">All Documents</a>
          <a href="#">Divisional Websites</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#news">Intro & News </a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">Programmes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">Benefits</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">Location</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HI, thanks for your suggestion. I tried it and now all my main links (Quicklinks, Intro & News etc) are arranging themselves vertically down in one column. The link components (All documents etc) will then overlap the wordings.

Comment: I do not see any "wordings" that are overlapped

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul class="navlist">
        <li>
          <div className="linkWrapper">
          <a href="#news">Quicklinks<i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="#">All Documents</a>
            <a href="#">Divisional Websites</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#news">Intro & News </a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">Programmes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">Benefits</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">Location</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };

// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
```

```
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* List for header */
.navlist {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.navlist li {
  float: left;
}

.navlist a{
  display:block;
  padding:8px;
  transition:0.3s;
}

.linkWrapper a:first-child {
  display:block;
} 

.navlist a:hover{
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.navlist a[href="#Quiclinks"] {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.navlist>li{
  position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the float for the submenu items adding

```
.navlist li div a {
  float: none;
}
```

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };

// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* List for header */
.navlist {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.navlist li {
  float: left;
}
.navlist li div a {
  float: none;
}

.navlist a{
  display:block;
  padding:8px;
  transition:0.3s;
}

.navlist a:hover{
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.navlist a[href="#Quiclinks"] {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.navlist>li{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul class="navlist">
        <li>
          <a href="#news">Quicklinks<i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
          <div>
            <a href="#">All Documents</a>
            <a href="#">Divisional Websites</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#news">Intro & News </a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">Programmes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">Benefits</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">Location</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. It runs properly in code snippet. But no changes is being seen for my part. I have a feeling it is something else, as the above is part of the code for a whole website. But header wise, this is all it is. So I really don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Your code snippet already set links to `display: block` and it works as expected, your issue seems to come from somewhere else, maybe css overrides elsewhere in your project ?

```
.navlist a{
  display:block;
  padding:8px;
  transition:0.3s;
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You're using `a` tags which by default are displayed inline, you could add some styling to your `a` to `display: block` or use a list :

```
<a href="#news">Quicklinks<i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">All Documents</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Divisional Websites</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

You may want to make this list unstyled to avoid dots.

Also to behave like a proper dropdown, this list should be hidden on first render and you will trigger the visibility with another js function listening on click event on your "Quicklinks" link. Something like :

```js
var button = document.getElementById("dropdownButton");
var menu = document.getElementById("dropdownMenu");

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {      
  menu.classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```

```css
 .hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="dropdownButton">Quicklinks</a>
<ul id="dropdownMenu" class="hidden">
  <li><a href="#">All Documents</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Divisional Websites</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Your original answer with the help of hiding the first render helped me. And yeah, the issue of link components not stacking up still appear. Ultimately, I would also believe that it's something else too that's causing this issue. Will cont working on it.

Comment: @masyitashariff did you try wrapping your links in a list as suggested in my answer ? Also, try this : `.navlist a { display: block !important; }`

Comment: Yeah, I did. I wrapped in the sense where I followed exactly as your answer and put my link components inside a <ul>

Comment: Well that's crazy, could you inspect this ul in your browser and look if there is some other css rule diplaying it `flex` or something like that ? Do you use any css library ?